# Disable, not hide a label

Tags: vb.net, label, disabled-control

I want to disable a label as soon as it is clicked however the code hides the label.

What I want is to disable it (make darkgrey and unclickable), not make it disappear.

```
  Label3.Enabled = False
```

Comment: Is this a label or Textbox control? Since a label doesn't provide any default interaction. Or did you add an onclick handler to your label?

Comment: i added a click event and expected it to work like a button qua enable disable also (not so)

Comment: when the `Label3.Enabled = False`? the result is actually hide?

Comment: Maybe your form `BackgroundColor` is the same as the `Label` color when is not enabled? And `Label3.Enabled = False` should disable the click event.

Comment: lol yes my background was black stuipid me :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your onclick event like this:

```
AddHandler Label3.Click, AddressOf MyClickMethod
```

Keep track of the state of your click and implement your method like this:

```
Private _isActive As Boolean

Public Sub MyClickMethod(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
   If _isActive Then
       RemoveHandler Label3.Click, AddressOf MyClickMethod
       _isActive = False
   Else
       AddHandler Label3.Click, AddressOf MyClickMethod
       _isActive = True
   EndIf
End Sub
```

Could be I'm missing some syntax, typing outside of visual studio